# Do your friends on average have more friends than you do?

Tags: graph-theory

I was watching this [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/nicholas_christakis_how_social_networks_predict_epidemics.html), which suggested that on average your friends tend to individually have more friends than you do. To define this more formally, we are comparing the average number of friends with:

```
average over each person p of:
    friend popularity, defined as:
    average over each friend f of p:
        number of friends f has
```

Intuitively, this seems to make sense. After all, if someone has a high number of friends, they will tend to increase friend popularity and affect a high number of people, while those people who decrease friend popularity only affect a low number of people. Does this result hold for all graphs?

Given a person `p`, let `t` stand for:

```
sum over each friend f of p:
    number of friends f has
```

It is pretty clear that `sum(t)=sum(f^2)` as a person with `f` friends has value of `f` towards their `f` friends value of `t`.

We are then trying to determine whether: `sum(t/f)>sum(f)` holds for all graphs.

Comment: As I recall, there was an informal discussion of something like this in one of Gladwell's books... that being said, this is probably more sociological than mathematical.

Comment: @J.M. I have provided an exact graph theory question that should be answerable mathematically. Does `sum(t/f)>sum(f)` hold for all graphs or is there a counter example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is yes, this holds for any graph (with weak inequality, as Jon points out).

Let's set up some notation. The graph of friendships is $G$. The set of vertices of $G$ (the people) is $V$; the set of edges (the friendships) is $E$. For a person $v$, the number of friends that person has is $\deg v$. The total number of people is $n$.

We want to show that
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{v \in V} \deg v \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{v \in V} \frac{1}{\deg v} \sum_{(u,v) \in E} \deg(u).$$

Cancel the $1/n$'s from both sides. After a little rewriting, we want to show that
$$\sum_{v \in V} \sum_{(u,v) \in E} 1 \leq \sum_{v \in V} \sum_{(u,v) \in E} \frac{\deg u}{\deg v}. \quad (*)$$

Let's consider what a given edge $(u,v)$ contributes to each side of $(*)$. On the left, it contributes $1+1=2$. On the right, it contributes $(\deg u)/(\deg v) + (\deg v)/(\deg u)$. For any two positive numbers $x$ and $y$, we have $2 \leq x/y+y/x$. So every edge contributes more to the right hand side of $(*)$ than to the left, and we have the claimed result.

Comment: By the way, a standard heuristic for this sort of problem: Try to get all your sums to be over the same index set, even at the expense of doing something like replacing $\deg v$ by $\sum_{(u,v) \in E} 1$.

Comment: That's a very nice proof. So the core observation is that each edge contributes 2 to the total number of friends, but `deg u/deg v+deg v/deg u` to the number obtained by adding each person's friend popularity. Also, its worthwhile noting that `2≤x/y+y/x` is easily proved using either calculus or the AM-GM inequality, just in case anyone doesn't know that

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: `deg u` and `deg v` are the degrees of the vertices *after* the graph has been completed. As it is worded, my comment could have been incorrectly interpreted to be referring to a situation where a graph is built one edge at a time and the degree is the degree *at this stage of construction*. That is probably why I didn't spot this solution - you consider the effect that each edge being added separately has at the end, rather than the effect right now.

Comment: +1 Nice! Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3275769/75923) on a special case. I expressed there that I had strong feelings that it could be generalized. I did not manage to find a proof on my own and arrived here later.

Answer (score 4):

Trivial comment, but I'm new so I have to post it as an answer: The strict inequality definitely doesn't hold in general, since the sums are equal for regular graphs.